# Dropwizard request processing is deferred

Tags: java, nginx, dropwizard

Dropwizard version: 0.9.2

I have a pretty simple dropwizard rest api on live servers.
There is a nginx in front of it.
For many request nginx shows that client timed out (status 499) as our service breached the SLA (150 ms).
On examining the access log and application log, it appears that the request reached dropwizard late (around 250ms after nginx had already declared the client timeout).

On enabling the debug logs at Dropwizard side, found out that the select thread is waking up late

I have tried multiple things including:
1) Setting the selector count to 200,300,400,500. None helped.
2) Increasing the acceptor count to 32,50,etc. 
3) Changing GC strategies 
4) Changing versions of dropwizard from 0.9.2 to 0.9.1.

Comment: - I would recommend using dropwizard 1.0.+

Comment: upgraded to 1.0.5, still have the same issue

Comment: I do not think this is DW. Try removing the nginix and talking to DW directly to see if this solves your issue (or at least determine if this is an issue with your application or your configuration)

Comment: Try using `tcpdump` to get the packet level data and then you can probably findout why it is behaving like this by analyzing the dump.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing threads in your config.yaml?

```
server:
   ...
   minThreads: 20
   maxThreads: 400
```

Comment: the default number of thread in dropwizard is 1024, i set the selector threads to 400, acceptor to 32, also 10 threads for admin port. There is a dedicated threadpool of size 100 . Remaining threads would be application threads. As suggested on internet, it is of no use if your application threads exceed the number of selectors. Advice was to keep it approximately equal to the selector threads. Also tried decreasing the idletimeout to 10s from default 30s. Also tried to configure the logback's async appender's queue size to check if it was blocking something.